# Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert __AS3__.vec::Vector.<com.clark::searchVO1>$ to __AS3__.vec.Vector.<com.clark::searchVO1>

Tags: json, actionscript-3, parsing, actionscript, session-variables

I want to first start off asking if anyone has any suggestions of any resource(books or examples) on parsing data/or Sessioning variables in AS3. I researched for some resources but those books or sites, does not really cover the topics i mentioned.

**I am trying to parse some JSON data from php into AS3 VO, then the VO into Vector file, the Vector File put the data into boxes, and that sits inside another as file for display. The boxes split the results into specific data. For example Box 1(ID1, Name1, Location1). Box 2(ID2,Name2,Location2). When the specific box is hit, the box will session the ID of that Box(listing), then parse it so it goes to the next AS file(to pull out the details from database) to display the details of that specific Listing.**

With the help from other post&poster, i managed to get to parsing the JSON back, but i have 2 errors, because i don't know which Valid vector i need to put as the parameter. And can i have some idea/advice on how i should create the "Sessioning ID" when the box is clicked?

> Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert
>   **AS3**.vec::Vector.$ to **AS3**.vec.Vector..
>       At this line `var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest(Vector.<searchVO1>);` in the file sresultnologin
>   below.
>        Error #1069: Property 0 not found on com.clark.SearchVectorTest and there is no default value. Starting from this line
>   `mySearchVector[i].nobed = searchVOs[i].nobed;` in the searchVO1 file
>   below Thanks for your time. SearchVO1

```
package com.clark
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;




       public class searchVO1 extends MovieClip {
        private var Arvariables:URLVariables;
        private var SrSend:URLRequest;
        private var SaLoader:URLLoader;
           public var nobed:String;
        public var zip:String;
        public var Location:String;
        public var price:String;
           public var callMethod:Function;

public var s1:searchpage = new searchpage ();

               public function searchVO1():void{

addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);                  // init
function onadded (event:Event):void{


            s1.x=-10;
            s1.y=10;

            addChild(s1);

             s1.searchs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ValidateAndsearch);


            // Build the varSend variable
            SrSend = new URLRequest("http://localhost/search.php");
            SrSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
                   Arvariables = new URLVariables;
            SrSend.data = Arvariables;

            SaLoader = new URLLoader();
            SaLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            SaLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,Asandler);


 // private methods

           function Asandler(event:Event):void{

 // retrieve data from php call
var resultString :String = event.target.data;
// parse result string as json object and cast it to array
var resultArray  :Array  = JSON.parse( resultString ) as Array;
// get the length of the result set
var len:int = resultArray.length;

// create vector of SearchVO
var searchVOs:Vector.<searchVO1> = new Vector.<searchVO1>();
// loop the result array
for( var i:int = 0; i<len; i++ )
{
    searchVOs[i] = new searchVO1();   
    searchVOs[i].nobed = resultArray[i].nobed;
    searchVOs[i].zip = resultArray[i].zip;
    searchVOs[i].Location = resultArray[i].Location;
    searchVOs[i].price =  resultArray[i].price;
}

// call a function to create your boxes

// or maybe create your SearchVector class and pass it your search vector
var mySearchVector:SearchVectorTest = new SearchVectorTest(searchVOs);
    for( var i:int = 0; i<len; i++ )
mySearchVector[i].nobed = searchVOs[i].nobed;
mySearchVector[i].zip = searchVOs[i].zip;
mySearchVector[i].Location = searchVOs[i].Location;
mySearchVector[i].price = searchVOs[i].price;
       }   
   }
   }

    public function searchVOs( nobed:String, zip:String, location:String, price:String )
        {
            this.nobed      = nobed;
            this.zip        = zip;
            this.Location   = Location;
            this.price      = price;
        }
        public function ValidateAndsearch (event:MouseEvent):void {

        // validate fields

         Arvariables.nobed = s1.nobed.text;
        Arvariables.zip = s1.zip.text;
            Arvariables.Location = s1.Location.text;
            Arvariables.price = s1.price.text;
    SaLoader.load(SrSend);
            var s7:sresultnologin = new sresultnologin()    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s7);




        }

       }

}
```

SearchVectorTest

```
package  com.clark
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class SearchVectorTest extends MovieClip 
    {
    public function SearchVectorTest(test:Vector.<searchVO1>) 
        {
            super();


                for (var j:int = 0; j < test.length; j++) 
            {

                trace(test[j].nobed);
                trace(test[j].zip);
                trace(test[j].Location);
                trace(test[j].price);



        }


            var currentY:int = 270;

            for (var k:int = 0; k < test.length; k++) 
            {
                var Bolder:Listing5 = new Listing5();

                Bolder.x=80;

                var bf:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf1:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf2:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf3:TextField = new TextField();

                bf3.width = 100;
                bf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

                bf.width = 100;
                bf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf1.width = 100;
                bf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.width = 100;
                bf1.y= bf.height+5;





                bf.text = test[k].nobed;
                bf1.text = test[k].zip;
                bf2.text = test[k].Location;
                bf3.text = test[k].price;

                bf1.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5

                bf3.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5


                bf.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5
                bf.y = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.15
                Bolder.addChild(bf);
                Bolder.addChild(bf1);
                Bolder.addChild(bf2);
                Bolder.addChild(bf3);



                Bolder.y = currentY;

                addChild(Bolder);
                currentY += Bolder.height + 35;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

sresultnologin

```
package com.clark

{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import fl.controls.Button;




       public class sresultnologin extends MovieClip {

public var s1:Searchreult = new Searchreult ();

               public function sresultnologin(){
                  // init



            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);
         function onadded (event:Event):void{



            s1.x=-10;
            s1.y=10;

            addChild(s1);
         }

var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest(Vector.<searchVO1>);
                 addChild (s3);


           }

}
}
```

Comment: it's strange, you have a variable searchVOs same named as a function searchVOs you don't have compile errors for that in your searchVO1 class ? an other thing, you create searchVO1 vector inside a searchVO1 class ? your SearchVectorTest class already contain your results why would you like to add it in your second loop ?

Comment: The only error i am having is Error #1069: Property 0 not found on mySearchVector[i].nobed = searchVOs[i].nobed; 
I created the searchVO1 to parse the JSON data step by step to the vector. I am not sure how. At the moment it displays the results in the output, but if i remove any of that, none of them come through. I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: you don't have to do mySearchVector[i].nobed = searchVOs[i].nobed; as mySearchVector already have all VOs passed in the constructor

Comment: I just tried it again, i removed the mySearchVector[i].nobed = searchVOs[i].nobed; the result displays in the output window, but i have no idea how to load that into the searchVectorTest as file

Comment: your SearchVectorTest class has the data in the test variable you can do what you want with it

Comment: But in the SearchVectorTest, it will trace the data, but it won't put them in the boxes though. But i put Textfield and the text=test[k].nobed and adding the text into a holder. But nothing appears

Comment: because you add your textFields inside your SearchVectorTest object but you daon't add your SearchVectorTest object to any container

Comment: :) Thanks, i will try it out, i didnt know i suppose to add the textfield in the VO field, thought i add them in the Vectortest file

Comment: I managed to do it!!! THANKS SO SO SO SO SOS OS SO SOS SO SO SO SO SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your mySearchVector Object isn't added to the display list, all it's content cannot be displayed ...

try it, it must work:

```
function Asandler(event:Event):void
{

    // retrieve data from php call
    var resultString :String = event.target.data;
    // parse result string as json object and cast it to array
    var resultArray  :Array  = JSON.parse( resultString ) as Array;
    // get the length of the result set
    var len:int = resultArray.length;

    // create vector of SearchVO
    var searchVOs:Vector.<searchVO1> = new Vector.<searchVO1>();
    // loop the result array
    for( var i:int = 0; i<len; i++ )
    {
        searchVOs[i]          = new searchVO1();   
        searchVOs[i].nobed    = resultArray[i].nobed;
        searchVOs[i].zip      = resultArray[i].zip;
        searchVOs[i].Location = resultArray[i].Location;
        searchVOs[i].price    = resultArray[i].price;
    }


    // create your SearchVector class and pass it your search vector
    var mySearchVector:SearchVectorTest = new SearchVectorTest(searchVOs);
    // add your searchVector to the display list
    addChild( mySearchVector );

    // REMOVE THIS BLOCK !!
    /* 
    for( var i:int = 0; i<len; i++ )
        mySearchVector[i].nobed = searchVOs[i].nobed;
        mySearchVector[i].zip = searchVOs[i].zip;
        mySearchVector[i].Location = searchVOs[i].Location;
        mySearchVector[i].price = searchVOs[i].price;
    } 
    */  
}
```

Comment: I added the boxes in the VO field, so i eliminated the VectorTest field, everything is done inside the VO file. But i will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

`var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest(Vector.<searchVO1>);` is you sending a reference to a class not an instance of an object of that type.

Change to either

```
var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest(new Vector.<searchVO1>());
```

or

```
var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest(Vector.<searchVO1>([]));
```

Comment: Hi yes! That part worked, wondering if you would have any idea about the Error #1069: Property 0 not found on mySearchVector[i].nobed = searchVOs[i].nobed; I am not sure how do i suppose to create a searchvector class and pass that information.

Comment: ow, that, is that because "mySearchVector" is a MovieClip and not a List? You are trying to iterate a movieclip... not a list of movieclips?